# Is there a way to pass the results of a CNN to another?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a classification problem with 4 different classes. The four classes are persian cat, european cat, golden retriever and german shepherd.

My intention is to somewhat incorporate hierarchical structure in the decision-making. To achieve that I made this hierarchy:

[image]

Classifier (a) decides if it's a cat or a dog and then passes the decision to the following classifier. Classifier (b) determines which kind of cat it is and classifier (c) what kind of dog.

I have already trained all the classifiers(a,b and c) separately and saved their best weights. I also made the confusion matrices of the 3 different classifiers(all 2 by 2 matrices), but how can I connect the classifiers among themselves? That is, how can I pass the result of classifier a to classifier b and c?

Each classifier has the same structure:

```
Resnet = ResNet101(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
model = tf.keras.Sequential(Resnet)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation="softmax"))
```

Comment: Why won't you train a model to classify 4 classes?

Comment: I want to make a comparison between this model and your suggestion. So I already made what you suggested @Frightera